# Determine RFC caller?

Tags: abap, saprfc

In `ST22, I found a short dump caused by a RFC in a infinite loop.

The problem is that I did not find any jobs that triggered the RFC, nor any errors in `SM58`.

How can I find out how that RFC was triggered? Which transaction should I check ?

In `ST22`, in the call stack is just subroutine pool `SAPMSSY1`

Comment: have you taken a look into transcation STAD? You can see which user triggered the rfc. Also you can double click the rfc to get some more info as to the partner IP the connections and the calls.

Answer (score 4):

You have a section "caller" in the short dump.

It provides only a very general information. There is the "call program".

[image]

Comment: The call is being made by another SAP system(let's call is X) to which I also have access. The call program is SAPLCSER. In system X, I checked if there are any jobs with that program, no results. No matching entries in SM58. In STAD I could not find any helpful info. Is there anything else to check ?

Comment: It won't be easy to trace anyway. If it's a standard program, open a ticket at SAP support. Jobs only refer the very first program to be called. SAPLCSER (function group CSER) is about CIF (SCM/APO?). You should also ask the people responsible of the calling system to check the logs.